# Is there an algorithm that matches constrained input to possible output?

Tags: algorithm

I'm working on a problem where a user provides a list of input products that can be turned into different end products. Each input product has a specific set of outputs it could become. The user also provides a list of expected output products and how much of each they want. I'm looking to see if there is a known algorithm for matching the various inputs to the outputs to meet the demand with as best of a fit as possible.

Example:

> Product A can become products X and Y
>   Product B can become products Y and Z
>
> There are 5 A and 7 B.
>   Can you make 3 X, 4 Y, and 6 Z?

I would like an approach that would help me find the output:

3 A -> X
2 A -> Y
2 B -> Y
5 B -> Z
Missing 1 Z

Comment: So you are looking for the allocation as well as yes/no?

Comment: "Product A can become products X and Y" This means that X can become either X *or* Y, not both X *and* Y at the same time, right?

Comment: Have done *any* work on finding a solution, and if so, what?

Comment: @cricket_007 - basically. I'm looking for an known algorithm that solves this type or problem.

Comment: @ScottHunter - I'm not asking for a working solution. Just looking to know if this is a problem with well known algorithms to guide an approach. If not, I will start from scratch.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - correct

(sorry for multiple comments, I can't reply to multiple people in one..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem by applying any of the [max flow algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) to a flow network constructed as follows:

- Add source node S and sink node T
- For each input product add node A<sub>i</sub>
- For each output product add node Z<sub>j</sub>
- For each input product add an edge from S with capacity equal to the number of the corresponding product
- For each output product add an edge to T with capacity equal to the desired number of the corresponding product
- From each A<sub>i</sub> and Z<sub>j</sub> add an edge with capacity equal to the number of A<sub>i</sub> product

Here is how the network would look for your example.

[image: Example]

If the max flow is equal to the total capacity entering T, a solution is defined by min cat; otherwise, a solution is not possible.

**Note:** If all you need is a yes/no answer, you could eliminate A<sub>i</sub> nodes, and add edges from S to Z<sub>j</sub>, with capacities equal to the total for this output over all input products (i.e. X=5, Y=12, and Z=7). This would produce the same decision result, but you wouldn't be able to find out how many input products of each kind need to be consumed in the process.

Comment: This looks great! I knew I had seen one in my algorithms class back in school, but couldn't find the right search to get the name. Thank you!